# Google classroom API

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I am new for Google Classroom API integration and want to confirm following queries can anyone please answer for my questions for my confirmation.

1- Classroom API is available only available for Google Apps for Education users not for the Gmail users just want to confirm this again.
2- Classroom API to get list of courses is only for student account not for the Teachers because I am getting empty value by using Teachers account.

Please reply me for above queries.

Thanks

Comment: 1.- That's correct it is only for Google Apps for Education accounts.
2.- can you describe how you are making the call?

Comment: I am using API URL to get the courses list https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list.
If I used Teachers account then its not giving me result but giving me result for Students account.
Thanks

Comment: does the teacher have any courses assigned?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, Classroom (and the Classroom API) is only available to [Google Apps for Education](https://www.google.com/edu/products/productivity-tools/) users.
2. If the teacher can see classes on https://classroom.google.com/ (not just classes they're "invited to teach") then they should also be able to see them via https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list.

Answer (score 0):

1. As of March 2017, [Google Classroom is now open to users without G Suite for Education accounts](https://www.blog.google/outreach-initiatives/education/google-classroom-now-open-even-more-learners/).  It works with Gmail accounts.  It's not currently available for G Suite (Google Apps) accounts that are not G Suite for Education.
2. See [mjs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34074427/1000655).